# How to bind the current date in sqlite for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Does anyone have an idea how to insert current date or bind the current date in sqlite for iphone app?

I have used this, to store a String:

```
sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 3, [Gjourney UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Is there any way to store the current date? In my datebase I make the Table `hello` in which i have the column `startdate` with a `DATETIME` dataType.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think try using like this it may help you.

```
dateExpires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 3)];
```

Cheers.....

Comment: What it will do can it take starting date auotmetically And please explain me more

Comment: can i set data type as DATETEXT for start date

Comment: Try to use the sqlite3_column_double instead of binding it as a text.Because the time stamp would be saved as double value.Thats why your app is crashing.....Just check it whether it helps you or not..

Comment: No My app is not getting crash It is successfully insert the value but When I am firing the (select startdate from hello ) it was not giving answer .that's way ask the can change the datatype as datetext

Comment: What code you compiled,did you use my code or your.And moreover have you set the data type as time stamp in your SQLite while you created the table there

Comment: I select your answer because it near to my question

Answer (score 2):

SQLite understands date/time values entered in the following formats. If the format is invalid, SQLite will not give an error, but the function call will return null.

1. YYYY-MM-DD
2. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
3. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
4. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
5. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
6. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
7. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
8. HH:MM
9. HH:MM:SS
10. HH:MM:SS.SSS
11. now
12. DDDD.DDDD    (julian day as floating-point number)

So code as follows,

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormat release];
```

Just insert this dateString value, SQLite will recognize it as a date.

Comment: can i set data type as DATETEXT for start date

Comment: @Shima: thats based on your requirement

Comment: Is that it will work .I mean to say DATETEXT datatype is available or not sqlite for iphone

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *date = [NSDate date];
```

it returns currunt date. save this date string to SQlite;

Comment: When you fire the select statement it will not show you answer

Comment: Becuse i have the startdate type as the DATETIME

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942188/sqlite-datetime-data-type-with-iphone-nsdate this link may be helpful for you.

Comment: can i set data type as DATETEXT for start date