# FMDatabase dateForColumn, does it work?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm using FMDatabase as sqlite wrapper for my iOS app,
there's one place where I have to extract a date. I go like that:

```
....
ac.date=[s dateForColumn:@"date"];
NSLog(@"Date %@", ac.date);
```

But debug output gives me the following:
Date 1970-01-01 00:33:32 +0000
Even though I've got dates like 2012-03-03 in my database, what can be wrong? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FMDatabase code wants dates in the database as seconds from 1/1/1970 ie Unix time - if you have dates as strings like like 2012-03-03 then you will have to explicitly convert then from NSString to NSDate.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942188/sqlite-datetime-data-type-with-iphone-nsdate) for example code

Or you could alter the FMDatabase code in FMDatabase.m to bind dates as strings