# convert date yyyy-MM-dd to string like /Date(1430604000000+0200)/ in swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, date-formatting

I need to convert date saved in a `NSDate` with format `yyyy-MM-dd` to `NSString` with format like `/Date(1430604000000+0200)/` in swift, because I have to save it in my DB SQLite.

In this way i convert /date()/ to nsdate yyyy-MM-dd:

```
var charactersToRemove: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
                var milliseconds:NSString = dateString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(charactersToRemove)
                var dateTemp:NSDate!
                if (milliseconds != "" && !milliseconds.isEqualToString("62135596800000") )
                {
                    var seconds:NSTimeInterval = milliseconds.doubleValue / 1000
                    dateTemp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)
                }
```

But now I need to reverse it. I need to convert nsdate `yyyy-MM-dd to string /date()/`.

Thank you.

Comment: Is 1430604000000+0200 just the UTC timestamp? If so, think about it. Using `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` you can get the timestamp from your date and from there it shouldn't be too difficult to replace the decimal in the double that is NSTimeInterval with a +

Comment: also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1000959/3810673

Answer (score 0):

I didn't add sign check but I ended up something like this.

```
let format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
formatter.dateFormat = format

var dateString = "2014-12-30" // your input date
let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString) 
let timestamp: NSTimeInterval = date!.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0

let result = String(format: "/Date(%.0f+%02d00)/", timestamp,formatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT/3600)
```

Comment: i combined your code with mine, i find out that it return "1970-01-17" instead of "2014-12-30", any idea?

Comment: What is the original date and time at GMT ?

Comment: I refactored the code. Can you provide your target date for testing?

Comment: Code returns timestamp in seconds, that was the problem